# How to create multi select picklist in vf page using slds

Tags: bootstrap, slds

Can anyone provide some idea or approach on how to create a multiselect picklist like below pic.

[image]

Comment: You can achieve similar by bootstrap multiselect plugin. Please see http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/